# Windows FFMPEG - convert a PNG to WMV of n seconds duration

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cmd

Been bumping my head into the walls for the last 2 days with FFMPEG Windows.
Basically I have a PNG. I want to generate a WMV of exactly 400 seconds - all done from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as:

```
ffmpeg -t 400 -loop_input -i input.png output.wmv
```

See the [docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) for information about `-loop_input` and [option order](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Description).

Comment: I'm using `ffmpeg -t 400 -loop 1 -i p.png -qscale 1 -s 1728x1080 -y video8.avi` but aside from taking forever (about 30 seconds for every 10 seconds of encoded movie) it doesn't compress anything. Even though the frames are literally the same.

Comment: Try setting the codec explicitly with `-codec:v <codec>` or changing the type of your output file to something more compressive like `.m4v`.

Comment: I went with MP4. It still takes a lot of time and CPU to encode but at least I can create a 4 hours video (over the night) and trim down from that one every time I need to attach audio to it.